# Lisp function getting wrong number of arguments

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've defined the following function **soma-n** where **n** is an integer and **l** is a list.

```
(defun soma-n (n l)
  (if (null l)
      ()
      (cons (+ (first l) n) (soma-n (rest l)))))
```

I'm trying to call it as follows, but it seems that one of the arguments is not sent, since I'm getting the following error:

```
(soma-n 3 '(1 2 3))
; SOMA-N got 1 arg, wanted at least 2.
```

What is the problem with the way I'm calling the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what you probably wanted

```
(defun soma-n (n l)
  (if (null l)
      ()
      (cons (+ (first l) n) (soma-n n (rest l)))))
```

you were passing just a list to recursive call of some-n

Comment: ahh, I miss that one thanks a lot!